# I am trying to pass values to a function from the reliability library but without much success. here is my sample data and code

Tags: function, undefined, reliability

**My sample data was as follows**

| Tag_Typ | Alpha_Estimate | Beta_Estimate | PM01_Avg_Cost | PM02_Avg_Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OLK-AC-101-14A_PM01 | 497.665 | 0.946584 | 1105.635 | 462.3833775 |
| OLK-AC-103-01_PM01 | 288.672 | 0.882831 | 1303.8875 | 478.744375 |
| OLK-AC-1105-01_PM01 | 164.282 | 0.787158 | 763.4475758 | 512.185814 |
| OLK-AC-236-05A_PM01 | 567.279 | 0.756839 | 640.718 | 450.3277778 |
| OLK-AC-276-05A_PM01 | 467.53 | 0.894773 | 1536.78625 | 439.78 |

**This my sample code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from reliability.Repairable_systems import optimal_replacement_time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\\EU_1_EQ_PM01_Cost.xlsx')
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Alpha_Estimate','Beta_Estimate','PM01_Avg_Cost','PM02_Avg_Cost'])

Alpha_Est=pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Alpha_Estimate'])
Beta_Est=pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Beta_Estimate'])
PM_Est=pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['PM02_Avg_Cost'])
CM_Est=pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['PM01_Avg_Cost'])
optimal_replacement_time(cost_PM=PM_Est, cost_CM=CM_Est, weibull_alpha=Alpha_Est, weibull_beta=Beta_Est,q=0)
plt.show()
```

I need to loop through the value set for each tag and pass those values to the Optimal replacement function to return the results.

[Sample Output]
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

I would appreciate any suggestions on how I can pass the values of the PM cost, PPM cost, and the distribution parameters alpha and beta in the function as I iterate through the tag-type and print the results for each tag. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't attach in code in the form of images. (For reasons see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13082649) To format code/data just put ``` before and after the code block.

Answer (score 0):

The core of your question is how to iterate through a list in Python. This will achieve what you're after:

```
import pandas as pd
from reliability.Repairable_systems import optimal_replacement_time

df = pd.read_excel(io=r"C:\Users\Matthew Reid\Desktop\sample_data.xlsx")
alpha = df["Alpha_Estimate"].tolist()
beta = df["Beta_Estimate"].tolist()
CM = df["PM01_Avg_Cost"].tolist()
PM = df["PM02_Avg_Cost"].tolist()

ORT = []
for i in range(len(alpha)):
    ort = optimal_replacement_time(cost_PM=PM[i], cost_CM=CM[i], weibull_alpha=alpha[i], weibull_beta=beta[i],q=0)
    ORT.append(ort.ORT)

print('List of the optimal replacement times:\n',ORT)
```

On a separate note, all of your beta values are less than 1. This means the hazard rate is decreasing (aka. infant mortality / early life failures). When you run the above script, each iteration will print the warning:

```
"WARNING: weibull_beta is < 1 so the hazard rate is decreasing, therefore preventative maintenance should not be conducted."
```

If you have any further questions, you know how to contact me :)

Comment: Thank you so much.  The code works fine on standalone execution.

Comment: The output end results: List of the optimal replacement times:
 [1492.9950000000001, 866.0160000000001, 492.846, 1701.837, 1402.59].